How can I fix this get search?
I'm trying to fix a problem in my application where I can't filter words by their meaning.

Example: wordMeaning = "order, request" | meaningSearch = "order"

The application thinks that the parameter is a number for some reason, saying that:

"Validation failed (numeric string is expected)"

Even if I try to do this in Postman, it doesn't work. But everything else does.
If anyone has any idea of how I can fix or change this, I'm open to suggestions! For example, I was thinking of implementing this filter on the frontend, but I'm not sure yet.
Here is the actual code:
Service:
getWordMeaning(userId: number, meaning: string) {
    return this.prisma.word.findMany({
      where: {
        meaning: { contains: meaning, mode: "insensitive"},
        userId,
      }
    })
}

Controller:
@Get(":meaning")
  getWordMeaning(@GetUser("id") userId: number, @Param("meaning") meaning: string) {
    return this.wordsService.getWordMeaning(userId, meaning);
  }

Test that I made:
describe("Get Word by Meaning", () => {
      it("Should get words by meaning", () => {
        return pactum
          .spec()
          .get("/words/{meaning}")
          .withPathParams("meaning", "$S{wordMeaning}")
          .withHeaders({ Authorization: "Bearer $S{userAt}" })
          .expectStatus(200)
          .expectBodyContains("$S{wordMeaning}");
      });
    });

